# Does infinity refer or represent quantity?

Tags: probability

It is my understanding that that to the extent the concept of number refers to some idea of quantity the concept of infinity should also do that - - if it does not then what exactly is the significance of that concept - - functional or some other? I would be happy to have any kind of answer.

Comment: I am sorry there is a grammatical omission. It should be Does infinity refer to quantity.

Comment: There is an "edit" button below the post which you can use to correct the grammar.

Answer (score 0):

"Infinity" can refer to several things. Quantity (or "cardinality", as we like to call it) is one of them, yes. For instance, the quantity of natural numbers is one type of infinity. The quantity of the real numbers is another.

A different notion of "infinity" is found when taking limits. $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ means "the limit as $x$ grows beyond any finite number". This doesn't mean $x$ becomes infinitely large, as it never grows beyond *all* of the numbers. It's just that any number is at some point passed. In this case $\infty$ refers to this concept of just getting larger and larger. And whether $x$ truly represents quantity here, that's up to what you're talking a limit of.